# TweenLite animation suddenly changing elements' position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, gsap

First of all, you can find a simplified demo of my code in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JocaPinto/o6uo658d/7/) and also below the question. I found that my problem happens the way I describe it in Google Chrome, so if you plan to try and fix the bug, please use that browser. I apologize if the code is not very well simplified; please consider that this is a snippet from a bigger project.

I'm working on a webapp that uses JQuery and GreenSock's TweenLite for animations.

This app consists on some menus that control everything, that are transitioned between using the `bodyChange()` function. This function has two parameters:

- `nextOrPrev`, that runs one animation or another based on the value
  provided (`"next"` or `"prev"`). Only the `"next"` animation is done yet, but that is not important for now. The `"prev"` animation, not yet used, just emits an `alert("prev")`.
- `bodyFunction`. The function provided will fill the body with the elements necessary for that menu, and the wrap them in a `#bodyWrap`.

In the demo I provide you with there are only two menus: The first one, `mainMenu`, with only a `#playButton`. When you click it, the `bodyChange()` function is called with the following parameters: `("next", playSettingsBody)`, `playSettings` being the second menu.

This is the problem: when you click the `playButton`, the button goes up a on the screen and then executes the TweenLite animation. I can't see, however, why does the button "jump up", instead of staying in the same place and execute the animation. This is probably due to a small mistake. What is it?

Thanks for any help.

```js
mainMenuBody();

function mainMenuBody() {
 $("body").append(
 //BUTTONS
 "<div id='playButton' class='mainButton'><div class='buttonText mainButtonText text'>PLAY</div></div>"
 );
 //WRAP
 $("body").wrapInner("<div id='bodyWrap'></div>");
 //BINDS
 $("#playButton").bind("click", function() {
  bodyChange("next", playSettingsBody);
 }); 
}

function bodyChange(nextOrPrev, bodyFunction) {

 switch (nextOrPrev) {
  case "next":
   //ANIMATION AND BODY CHANGE
   TweenLite.to($("#bodyWrap"), .4, {
     ease: Power2.easeIn,
     transform: "rotateY(90deg)",
     onComplete: function(){
      $("body").empty();
     //NEW STUFF
      bodyFunction();
      TweenLite.from($("#bodyWrap"), .4, {
       ease: Power2.easeOut,
       transform: "rotateY(90deg)"
      });
     }
   });
   //END OF ANIMATION AND BODY CHANGE
   break;

  case "prev":
   alert("prev");
 }
}

function playSettingsBody() {
 $("body").append(
 "<p class='text' id='CYTText'>This is the second menu!</p>"
  );
}
```

```css
body{
 background-image: url("../resources/pics/Vignette2.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-color: #02BFC1;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin: 0;
 
 }

.text {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family:Bebas Neue;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 cursor: default;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

 }
  
 .mainButton {
 -webkit-transform:scale(1);
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 10px solid #F1F2F0;
 text-align:center;
 background-color: #F37C2B;
 /*background:#5F4A21;*/
 display: table;
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 top: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
  
 .mainButtonText {
 position: relative;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 -webkit-transform:scale(1);
 font-size: 90px;
 text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is my edit what you are after?

Comment: Is there something I can change about the answer to make it a more suitable answer?

Comment: @Dan I tried your method but it didn't work in the main project. As I have learnt in the GSAP forum,  the problem is actually due to a querk in the CSS and has nothing to do with the animation. I decided to not do the animation for now as it is not essential to the overall project and fix the problem at a later stage. Thank you for you answer anyway :)

Comment: May I ask what didn't work about my answer?

Comment: It might have been my sloppy adaptation as your effect was different that the one I was going for. I will revisit this in the future and it might work with a better adaptation.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused in your `.mainButton` class. Your code looks a little like this.

```
.mainButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    //rest
}
```

By removing the line `bottom: 0;` your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/o6uo658d/9/) now works as expected. However, if you remove the line `top: 150px;` instead and leave in the `bottom: 0` the problem still occurs. Unfortunately, I cannot provide an explanation for this. It might be worth posting a question on the GSAP forums inquiring about why this occurs works when positioning using `bottom` but not when using `top`

**Edit**
Since you need `bottom: 0` and I wasn't able to fix your code I wrote an example which works using `Timeline`, a GSAP plugin. You can see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/zsonbgpu/4/) or the code example below.

```js
var tl = new TimelineMax();
tl.pause();
tl.fromTo($("#click"), 1, {rotationY: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut}, {rotationY: 90, transformOrigin:"right", ease: Power2.easeOut})
  .set($("#click2"), {css:{display: "table"}}, "-=0.6")
  .fromTo($("#click2"), 1, {rotationY: -90, ease: Power2.easeOut}, {rotationY: 0, transformOrigin:"left", ease: Power2.easeOut}, "-=0.6");

$("#click").click(function() {
  tl.play();
});

$("#click2").click(function() {
  tl.reverse();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../resources/pics/Vignette2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: #02BFC1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.one, div.two {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #F37C2B;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 10px solid #F1F2F0;
}
div.one .text, div.two .text {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  font-size: 90px;
}
div.two {
  display: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  background: none;
}
div.two .text {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div id="click" class="one">
  <div class="text">
    Play
  </div>
</div>

<div id="click2" class="two">
  <div class="text">
    Second Menu
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need that `bottom: 0` though. Besides, the next menu is also above where it's supposed to be anyway. Thank you anyway, if I can't find help here I will post on the GSAP forum.

Comment: @JocaPinto I updated my answer with a working example which is as you wanted I think. Let me know if it isn't